# Disable Connected / Connection Lost bezels on OS X

Tags: macos, bluetooth

Is there a way to disable the notifications shown when the connection status of a Bluetooth device changes? (Either globally or per device.)

You could remove `/System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin`, but not without disabling other similar bezels.